# Find the determinant using co-factoring

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried finding the determinant of A using the co-factors technique, yet always get it wrong, This is my approach:

A = $$ 
 \begin{matrix}
 3  & 1 & 0  \\
 -2 & -4 & 3 \\        
 5 & 4 & -2 \\
 \end{matrix}
$$

B = $$ 
 \begin{matrix}
 -4 &  3 \\
 4 & -2 \\        
  \end{matrix}
$$

C = $$ 
 \begin{matrix}
 -2 &  3 \\
  5 & -2 \\        
  \end{matrix}
$$

D = $$ 
 \begin{matrix}
 -2 & -4 \\
 5 & 4 \\        
  \end{matrix}
$$

|A|= (3)* |A|+ (1)*|B| + (0)*|D|
|A| = (3)(-4) + (-11)
|A| = -21

Which is wrong, I looked up the solution, it is -1

sorry for my bad writing, I am new to the  website.

Comment: You forgot that the signs alternate.

Comment: det(B)=-4   det(C)= -11  det(D)= 12. 3*(-4) -1*(-11) + 0*12 = -1. Remeber the pattern goes like this: + - + - + etc. So you need a “minus-sign” in front of your “1”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is somewhat wrong:

$${\mathrm{det}}(A) = 3 \cdot {\mathrm{det}}(B) + (-1) \cdot 1 \cdot {\mathrm{det}}(C) + 0 \cdot {\mathrm{det}}(D) = -1$$.

Comment: My text book says the formula is:
|A| = $$\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{kj})*(A_{kj}) =$$

Comment: In that case $j$ is fixed. Which means you may expand through any column. Similar principle work for expansion through rows. Here you are expanding through first row:  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{1k}) \ast (A_{1k})$$. Also this means $A_{1k}$ include the sign.

Comment: @Anttarm To put it another way, $A_{kj}$ in that formula isn’t simply the determinant of the submatrix with that row and column deleted. It’s the _cofactor_, which includes a factor of $(-1)^{k+j}$.

Comment: This is the best ahaha moment that I had in a while